# I’m using a multilanguage script to change from lanquage. Now I’m having troubles in using by the image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I am new for script and jQuery

I’m using a multilanguage script to change from language. Now I'm having troubles to change from a language by using the image,

```
<a href="#"><img src="/flags/us.png" alt="en_EN" /></a>
<a href="#"><img src="/flags/it.png" alt="it_IT" /></a>
<a href="#"><img src="/flags/fr.png" alt="fr_FR" /></a>
```

here after i dnot know how to use this image tag

what i want from this image tag , when i am click this image i want the alt value of corresponding image click.
Hoe to get it... 
its possible or else give any other idea

thanks
Kumar

Answer (score 0):

Put a class in your anchor and try this

```
<a href="#" class="lang"><img src="/flags/us.png" alt="en_EN" /></a>
<a href="#" class="lang"><img src="/flags/it.png" alt="it_IT" /></a>
<a href="#" class="lang"><img src="/flags/fr.png" alt="fr_FR" /></a>

$('a.lang img').click(function(){
    var alt=$(this).attr('alt');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a class='lang_link' href="#"><img src="/flags/us.png" alt="en_EN" /></a>
```

Assuming your links have a class of `lang_link`, you can look inside the link to see what language should be chosen.

```
$('.lang_link').click(function(){
   var lang = $(this).find('img:first').attr('alt');
});
```

Comment: thanks John.but will you explain where i can place the jquery code and how? here before i am not work with script and jquery.

Comment: You'd have to place it in your page where you want to capture the click. Place it at the bottom of the page. I answered with jquery because you had that tagged, you might want to go to jquery.com and familiarize yourself with the concepts.

Comment: Hi i wrote the code like this but its not execute, here before add any other script? <script type="text/javascript">
  $('.lang_link').click(function(){
   var lang = $(this).find('img:first').attr('alt');
}); alert("hi");
  });  
 </script>

Comment: Have you added jquery to the top? And the classes to your links?